# TFS2017: Code search in excel files

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using the Code Search extension/feature to look into source control files and I noticed that is not returning any results for .xls files content although is returning result for .xlt files content.

It's possible to enable the search into .xls files also?

Comment: I haven't tried, but you may be able to configure Elastic Search with this plugin. https://github.com/chetanganatra/Excel-2-Elasticsearch/blob/master/README.md